# How to plot a categorical variable using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data I'm using to produce my figure.Now, I want to use these data to produce a facet according to the land use type.Is it possible to do this. Can Anyone give me some advice? Thank you.

```
Variables   Cropland    Forest  Shrub   Urban   Water   Baresoil    MeanDecreaseAccuaracy   MeanDecreaseGini
band1   23.152  14.686  30.012  26.866  12.976  9.767   33.991  142.946
band2   23.359  19.116  30.077  23.961  14.12   11.793  32.729  165.892
band3   24.835  21.59   17.912  18.49   14.806  23.961  32.254  169.372
band4   25.709  34.052  20.737  23.17   13.894  25.297  36.721  209.631
band5   20.158  29.281  24.762  25.535  18.537  14.182  36.525  141.047
band6   32.447  25.134  24.8    35.59   22.485  16.168  40.496  232.536
band7   26.135  41.411  36.753  26.935  19.767  9.806   39.886  226.782
band8   2.46    1.93    1.872   -0.434  -0.088  4.831   4.315   5.334
```

Comment: For future questions, please use ```dput()``` to include your data (though the sample is appreciated!) and also show an attempt at what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry about that. Because there are some rules I am not understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again: *Please show what you've tried next time*, along with a sample of data using `dput`.

Note that I melted the data into a long format and then used "variable" as the facet. If you wanted to facet horizontally try `facet_grid(.~ variable)`, where the dot just means "everything else" and the ~ means "facet by".

```
df = melt(df, id.vars = c("Variables"))

>head(df)
 Variables variable  value
     band1 Cropland 23.152
     band2 Cropland 23.359
     band3 Cropland 24.835
     band4 Cropland 25.709
     band5 Cropland 20.158
     band6 Cropland 32.447

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Variables, y = value)) + 
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

[image]